# Do conductor plates encloising charged particles exert a force on one another due to the charges induced on them? How to calculate in a 1D model

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, gauss-law, method-of-images

[image]

I would very much appreciate some guidance on the below.

Consider a one-dimensional world as depicted in the attached figure.

- We have two (lets say positively charged) particles enclosed by two conductor plates
- One plate is at $x=0$ and the other at $x=L$. The particles are at $x_1$ and $x_2$ with respective charges $q_1$ and $q_2$

From my understanding:

- The postively charged particles will induce a charge on the conductor plates
- The positively charged particles will not feel a net force from the charge induced on the conductor plates due to Gauss' law (the conductor plates enclose the particles in this one-dimensional model)
- The conductor plates will experience a force from the charged particles which can be decuded using the method of images. This is calculated by assuming a ficticious oppostively charged particle is at the opposite side of the plate. The conductor plate feels a force from each of the particles by effectively assuming the particle was doulbe the distance away from the conductor plate (and the conudctor plate has opposite charge)
- $k$ is Coulomb's constant in the attached image

The part I am strugling with is:

- Does the conductor plate also feel a force from the other opposite conductor plate? If so, how do I calculate it?

Comment: A one dimension world has no "plates" in a second direction.

Comment: @trula My focus is on a 1D model to show the feasibility of a quantum phenomenon in 3D. I aim to either derive a 1D analogue for a 3D scenario or formulate an answer that provides insight, supporting why it can be overlooked in my broader argument.

Comment: This does not account for a "plate" in 1 d being  just a point. So your model is in 2d.